# Choose specific divs in grid

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I have **divs** from 1-6 and I need to change properties in divs from 2-5. I need to know if it is possible with nth-child or not. Because I can't find anything.

Comment: Simply add a class to those divs. There is no easier solution.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, by providing  a  number to  the  nth selector you can choose that div

for example

```
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

would choose  the  second  child, so in your case  you can repeat  it  for all the  divs you need to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 not operators, wich simply exclude 1 element from the selection:

```
 .parentclass div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, ill definitly try to do that in the future:)